# Another Git process seems to be running in this repository

Tags: git

I'm trying to learn how to use Git and have created a small project with an HTML, CSS, and JavaScript file. I made a branch from my basically empty project and then made some changes to my code. I tried staging the changes, but I get the following error message:

```
Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

Granted, I did run into problems trying to commit my empty project earlier and just quit [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) since I didn't know how to get out of where I somehow had gotten.

Is there a way for me to fix this or should I just start a new repository?

Comment: It seems like there is definitely another process running rn, possibly in another terminal tab?

Comment: Open task manager and see what else is running.  You might also be abld to use Process Explorer, if you have that installed.

Comment: Try using git bash, command Line or GUI then you can unlock the locked git

Answer (score 2425, accepted):

Try deleting `index.lock` file in your `.git` directory or in one of your **worktrees** `.git/worktrees/*/index.lock` if you are in a worktree.

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

Such problems generally occur when you execute two `git` commands simultaneously; maybe one from the command prompt and one from an IDE.

Comment: I got following error:

rm: cannot remove '.git/index.lock': Device or resource busy

Comment: remove with `rm -f .git/index.lock`

Comment: For CocoaPods, try to remove `Podfile.lock`.

Comment: .lock file does not exist on windows, remove index.lock file

Comment: Worked for me too, Thanks. I wonder why this answer is not mark as accepted yet.
Command sequence: 
1) find | grep '\.lock$'
2) rm -f ./.git/index.lock

Comment: If you get error: rm: cannot remove '.git/index.lock': Device or resource busy, restart your computer and try rm -f ./.git/index.lock again.

Comment: Thanks, Its working.
but I am remove whole project in my local and then upload whole project in Bit Bucket its not working and I am close my IDE, then why problem occur, pls let me know, If you have suggestion.

Comment: If there is no `index.lock` file there, check for `HEAD.lock`· Removing it solved the problem for me.

Comment: @YuvrajPatil In case of message: " Device or resource busy" - end all Git processes using Task Manager

Comment: I also had to remove another .lock file in the remote repository to have it fixed.

Comment: In Git 2.11.0.windows.1 the file name is just index. I did not delete it. I just renamed it temporary and then the push worked. After this, I renamed index to its original name.

Comment: @DanielShatz deleting `HEAD.lock` on Windows 10 (using Sourcetree) did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Just run rm -f .git/index.lock and then regular $ git add . command.

Comment: git rm -f .git/index.lock not worked for me.got previous error as same. I deleted that index.lock file manually and it worked.

Comment: In my case I found packed-refs.lock in git folder, I deleted and works for me

Comment: In my experience deleting the .lock file is very dangerous, I lost all my uncommitted work

Comment: I had a lock file on my .modules/odoo folder shallow.lock. Renamed it and it worked fine.

Comment: use -Force -f is ambiguous possible matches -Filter -Force use:

rm -Force .git/index.lock

Comment: On Windows pwsh just use `-Force`.

Comment: I did this: `rm -f .git/index.lock`. it fixed my problem but It raised a new error saying that vscode installation is corrupt. Now I have to reinstall VSCode.

Comment: I deleted `shallow.lock` and I have no idea why that did the trick when I couldn't find other files mentioned above.

Comment: Occasionally, Windows will give you an "Invalid Switch" error if you do this. It is advised to use backslashes (\) instead of forward slashes (/) to avoid this. i.e. del .git\index.lock

Answer (score 151):

Use the below command in the root directory of the application. This will delete the index.lock file and release the active lock.

```
rm .git/index.lock
```

Comment: I also had to close Sublime-Text because it had a git plugin. Another IDE connected to git likely has the same problem

Comment: In my experience deleting the .lock file is very dangerous, I lost all my uncommitted work

Answer (score 52):

Deleting my commit message worked for me.

```
rm .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

It then said.

> fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': Unable to create '.git/refs/heads/[your-branch-name].lock': File exists.

Do notice that your branch name might be different than mine. You can delete this lock file by doing;

```
rm .git/refs/heads/[your-branch-name].lock
```

Comment: This worked when I had tried to commit with docker-compose up in the background.

Answer (score 36):

If you are a [Windows](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) user, there will be the error *'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command*. That's because *rm* is a Linux command. So in Windows, you can use the below to remove the *index.lock* file inside the *.git* folder:

```
del -f .git/index.lock
```

If it doesn't work, try removing manually. If you cannot find the folder *.git* first turn on the "Show hidden files folders and drives" setting.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Windows!
Parameter "f" is not recognized.

Comment: Occasionally, Windows will give you an **"Invalid Switch"** error if you do this. It is advised to use backslashes **(\\)** instead of forward slashes **(/)** to avoid this.

i.e. `del .git\index.lock`

Comment: @WilliamDewayneCorrinIII thanks for your inputs on 'Invalid switch' scenario.... it saved my time. :)

Comment: In my experience deleting the .lock file is very dangerous, I lost all my uncommitted work

Comment: Unless this is for [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell), it is an example of the ***completely bogus*** answers that are submitted to Stack Overflow just to get reputation points. CMD's [DEL](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html) does not have the `-f` option. In PowerShell, [`rm` is an alias](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2019/10/powershell-aliases-and-missing.html) for [Remove-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849765.aspx). It can probably also call through to the regular `del`, but that doesn't change the options for `del`.

Comment: An alternative explanation is a mixup of keyboard layouts, [US keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#Windows_keyboards) vs. some other layout, say a [Spanish keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QWERTY_keyboard_language_variants#Spanish). Or plagiarised from a place where the mixup happened.

Comment: Windows also traditionally has trouble dealing with files whose file name begins with a dot.

Comment: OK, 'del' is also [an alias](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2019/10/powershell-aliases-and-missing.html) for [Remove-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849765.aspx) in PowerShell (together with `erase`, `rd`, `ri`, `rm`, and `rmdir`).

Comment: If the answer is qualified with PowerShell it may or may not make sense.

Comment: I've experienced the same problem ("Another git process ...") and I use Windows. I run  `DEL  .git\index.lock` in the CMD terminal and fixed the problem. Also `DEL /F` would be the equivalent in WINDOWS CMD of  `rm -f`, that forces to delete read-only files. Nevertheless, I did not have to use `/F` to fix the problem

Answer (score 30):

OK, I ended up getting it to work by running `git rm .git/index.lock`

It's weird because I did that a few times before to no avail, but hey computers, right?

Comment: No need to use `git rm` here, just `rm` is sufficient. `index.lock` is not a file meant to be tracked by git.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to delete the several of those `.lock` files;

```
.git/refs/heads/<branch_name>.lock
```

you can remove all at once by this way:

```
find -name "*.lock" -exec xargs rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are on [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell), use [rm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) ([an alias](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2019/10/powershell-aliases-and-missing.html) for [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item)):

`rm -Force .git/index.lock`

Comment: I also could solve the issue using '-Force' flag. The system threw ambiguous error between '-Force' and '-Filter'.

Comment: Note: `rm` in PowerShell [is an alias](https://pvm-professionalengineering.blogspot.com/2019/10/powershell-aliases-and-missing.html) for cmdlet *[Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item)*. Other aliases for *Remove-Item* are `del`, `erase`, `rd`, `ri`, and `rmdir`.

Answer (score 11):

Use the following command in case you are facing *Another Git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g., an editor opened by 'git commit'*, please make sure all processes are terminated and then try again. If it still fails, a Git process may have crashed in this repository earlier:

remove the file manually to continue.

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
git reset
```

And after the reset command, use `git status`, `git add`, and `git commit -a` or `git commit -m "your message"`, `git push origin master`.

Comment: I kept seeing the `.git/index.lock` file be recreated the moment I deleted it. `git reset` stopped that happening for whatever reason. 

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me and while [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) kept telling me the lock file exists, there wasn't any such a file there for me to remove. So I just checked out another branch and then returned to the original branch and noticed this change fixed the issue.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods) and at some point botched an update or install (manually killed it or something), try

1. Removing the `index.lock` file (in `.git/index.lock`)
2. Remove your `Podfile.lock` file.
3. Do a new `pod update`
4. Try issuing the Git command that was failing (in my case it was a `git add .`)

Comment: It was removing the Podfile.lock I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Delete file `index.lock` in here:

```
<path to your repo>/.git/index.lock
```

Also, if your repository has [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), delete all `index.lock` files in here as well:

```
<path to your repo>/.git/modules/<path to your submodule>/index.lock
```

Comment: The submodules part was what I needed

Comment: In my experience deleting the .lock file is very dangerous, I lost all my uncommitted work

Answer (score 8):

This might also come from another application or plugin that uses Git.
For example, [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements). In my case, it seemed some process got stuck in Sourcetree regarding Git. So deleting the *index.lock* file only didn't work for me. I'd to delete sourcetreeconfig in the *.git* folder in the project directory and it worked.

```
rm -rf .git/index.lock
rm -rf .git/sourcetreeconfig
```

Answer (score 7):

The error code will give you the full path of the file. Copy that path and delete the file.

For example,

```
fatal: Unable to create '/Users/username/Development/project/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

```
rm -rf fullPathOftheFile
```

```
rm -rf /Users/username/Development/project/.git/index.lock
```

Answer (score 6):

For me the problem was simpler. This was in [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements), so I'm not sure how much it'll apply to regular solutions, but I accidentally had my master branch selected trying to make a commit rather than my uncommitted changes.

This wouldn't normally be a problem, but I had already preemptively entered a commit message, so I could track what I was doing for that little sprint I was on.

Basically, I started a commit on the uncommitted branch and was accidentally trying to start another commit on my master branch.

Answer (score 5):

It may be happening your **branch** is corrupted. Create a new branch by `git branch #check branch`. I have created a new branch and it is working.

```
branch -b "main"
git checkout -b "main"  # Main is new branch
git add .
git commit -m "all files"
git remote add origin # **YOUR REPO**  https://github.com/tarun-techmarbles/wp-dump-sql-git-push.git
git push origin main  # Push with new branch
```

Answer (score 5):

Though there is an alternative in the previous answer, that didn't solve mine.

In my case, I delete the "git" plugin in [./zshrc](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh#Configuration) and reboot the computer. Then the issue is gone. I guess the [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (executable `zsh`) plugin had done something conflicting with the original Git command.

Comment: On Mac? Z shell is [the default shell in macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina#Removed_or_changed_components) (Catalina) and later.

Comment: Probably not; the dates don't line up.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error while `pod update`. I solved it by deleting the `index.lock` file in [CocoaPods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CocoaPods)'s `.git` directory.

```
rm -f /Users/my_user_name/.cocoapods/repos/master/.git/index.lock
```

Answer (score 3):

`rm -f .git/index.lock` didn't help, because I had a *locked* file that couldn't be deleted. So, `index.lock` also had been *captured* by some application.

In Windows I downloaded an alternative to `Unlocker` called `Lock Hunter` and deleted both files. `Git` captured them.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issues when I tried to staged a file in [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements).

To solve this, go to the *.git* folder in the project directory and manually delete file *index.lock* and you are done.

Comment: Actually I find in SourceTree that it is usually sufficient to wait a few seconds and try again.

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was as simple as closing my IDE and then checking out.  A teammate of mine had accepted my [PR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Pull_requests) and merged the code via [TFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server).  Removing the .lock files did not work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements). But there weren't any *index.lock* file on my host at all. I've found the **packed-refs.lock** file, and after deleting it, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

Navigating to the project directory and deleted the index.lock file solved the problem for me.

Comment: Same for me, simply deleting it worked on my Windows system.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. The issue was that I had tried to push my code with an [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file (used as a data set) which had a size of 1.3 GB.

The solution was to add this file into *[.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)* and then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

- My Mac was slow, so I ran two `git commit`s: one executed and the second was blocked by the first.
- I tried `rm -f .git/index.lock`

  - `rm .git/refs/heads/[your-branch-name].lock`
- `<path to your repo>/.git/index.lock`
- `<path to your repo>/.git/modules/<path to your submodule>/index.lock`

And:

1. `find | grep '\.lock$'`
2. `rm -f ./.git/index.lock` this was useful to check - no `.lock` file was lurking

I did what [Chloe did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004148/another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository/62485220#62485220): I checked out of my IDE, exited, and looked at a `git-status` once more. Then ran a `$git add . $git commit -m'msg' $git push`

It cleared the two terminals that were running commands and solved the problem.

A slow Mac has caused this problem before, so now I just wait for a bit before running a second commit that conflicts with the first.

Answer (score 2):

First, run

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

And then run

```
git reset --hard
```

in your command prompt or [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway).

Answer (score 2):

If you unfortunately have used your git or git remove from git bus or you can't commit your code and "git add ." and upload code remotely then check the following.

This command ...
**suppose your error tyepe**

```
Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

- open git bus or Windows PowerShell
- then use this command

  `rm .git/index.lock`

Comment: What is "git bus"? Do you mean [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway)?

Answer (score 2):

In my case it wasn't the `index.lock` file but the `HEAD.lock` file that was creating the problem.
Delete Head.lock file, fixed the issue

> rm -force .git/HEAD.lock

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I had to do a little more to resolve this.

First, I deleted file *index.lock*, and then I cloned fresh code from an existing Git repository location. I had my code changes in separated location. I copied the *.git* folder and the [.gitignore file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file and pasted in the code folder where I had made code changes.

Then I tried to commit and push, and it worked smoothly.
May be this information will be helpful if your problem doesn't by the above given solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you wind up here based on the question's title ("Another git process seems to be running in this repository"), note that the accepted answer will not be directly applicable to you if the message in this question's title is preceded by another message like the one below:

> fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': Unable to create '/<PATH>/<TO>/<REPO>/.git/refs/heads/<BRANCH>.lock': File exists.

In this case, you should delete that file (*<BRANCH>.lock*) instead of *.git/index.lock*.

Answer (score 1):

**It works for me. I got same error.**

Delete the `HEAD.lock` file on Windows 10. Now I can commit and push my changes on remote.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) IDE.

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

The above command didn't work. Instead, try the one below:

```
rm -force .git/index.lock
```

[PyCharm IDE terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnT8u.png)

[PyCharm IDE terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf5nN.png)

Answer (score 1):

[Obnoxious screenshot of something that should be posted as text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKv0o.png)

If this is the case with you then it is very easy to solve. The problem will be solved by following the steps below.

1. Enter the hidden folder of Git in the folder where you are working.
2. Delete "index.lock" file
3. Check you Git status using "git status" command
4. If your file nor committed, you have to commit you file using "git add --all" command
5. Again check your Git status, and stage the file, and commit

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72210425/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was the following:

1. As the previous answer show:

   ```
   rm -force .git/index.lock
   ```
2. Check out to any other branch. Check back to your branch.

Comment: `rm -force` in what environment? [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) on [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux)? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, guess it should work on every unix system

Answer (score 0):

In addition to deleting the lock file in your `.git` folder, if you are using Visual Studio Code and the [Git Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph) extension, try to uninstall it and then install it back again. It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this command,

```
del /f index.lock
```

and you get the following response,

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

You can restart the *git.exe* process in Windows by using a program like [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/). When Git restarts, the lock goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Related issue: I had *two automations* running on the same Git repository *in parallel*.

But they should not be running, so I fixed the automation to remove the duplication.

Comment: What do you mean by *"two automations"* and *"the automation"*? Two scripts? Or something else? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue. I am a Windows user, so all of the previous answers are by using command line [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) or any other. I used the following approach manually and it worked for me:

**Step 1:**

Go to the project directory you are trying to push.

In my case, it is E--Mobile

[image]

**Step 2:**

Enable show hidden folder in the folders **view** **settings**

[image]

**Step 3:**

After enabling **show hidden folder**, you will get **.git** file in the project directories.
Open **.git** folder and find the index.lock file there and delete it.

[image]

Now you can push the code easily.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all replies here about different `.lock` files, to those who even can't remove it, just make sure the file itself is not locked by another process/terminal session by doing the `lsof` command:

An example of the command:

`sudo lsof .git/index.lock`

The output might show you a process that holds it if there is any. It might be tricky to get rid of it, but kill of a process or machine restart should be helpful in such cases.

It relates to other .lock files across `.git` folders, so make sure there are no other `.lock` files inside.

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious, but it's worth mentioning that you might be getting this error message if you are combining commands where the first command has a lot of work to do.

For example, if you are doing something like this where you combine commands with "&&":

```
git add --all && git commit -m "Commit message"
```

Try splitting it up into separate commands to so that the first command has all the time it needs to finish.

Example:

```
git add --all
```

Then run the next part once the first command has finished:

```
git commit -m "Commit message"
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried everything above not worked
then I tried delete index.lock file manually in file explorer
usually this file inside .git file this file only visible if you check box hidden file
[.git file after checked hidden files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ybmm.png)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, just run the command: `yarn add commitizen -D`

Then everything is OK!

Answer (score -1):

Inside the *.git* folder, delete the *index.lock* file and try again to commit or add. It'll *work*.

Comment: Duplicated as it is already specified in a number of existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just starting to learn Python, and I came across this problem. After reading through and trying all the possible solutions offered for this problem, none actually worked for me. I use a Windows 10 64-bit system. Visual Studio Code text editor.

So I simply copied and pasted the venv folder into the .git folder, and that was it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the "venv folder"? Related to a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? Which one?