# Unable to git add env/bin directory after creating virtualenv

Tags: python, git, virtualenv

I am really new to Python and the virtualenv needed to set up a project. I dont know whether the directories generated by `virtualenv` should be gitignored or staged and committed.

I narrowed it down to the myproject/env/bin directory that doesn't seem to want to be staged. After running `git add env/bin` once I get.

`[1]    16599 killed     git add env/bin`

And then after running the same `git add env/bin` again I get.

```
 Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
 an editor opened by 'git commit'....
```

There are no other git process running. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another git process seems to be running in this repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004148/another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository)

Comment: @drdaeman yes I saw this post and deleted the `.git/index.lock` file but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through a few other Python/Django repositories on Github, I see that most have add the `env/bin`, `env/include` and `env/lib` directories (generated by virtualenv) to their `.gitignore` file. I'll take this at face value and move on til I have a better understanding of virtualenv. Thanks!