# Git not working after updating Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

After I have updated my Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.3.2, Git is not working now so I am unable to commit/pull/push etc. It's giving `Pull operation Failed` error. Also getting this error:

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an
>   editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are
>   terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process may have
>   crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to
>   continue.

Comment: I use VS 2017 with Git since CTP2. There's nothing wrong with VS 2017 and Git. What did you try, what happened? Can you work with git from TortoiseGit or the command line?

Comment: With command line also its giving the same error: "Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue."

Comment: Then the error has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another git process seems to be running in this repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004148/another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository)

Comment: I've got the similar issue after upgrading to VS 2017 v15.3.5 today. It stopped working for _all_ my repos, I cannot find any `.lock` files (hidden files enabled). The same thing happens if I clone a new repo. Tried to reinstall Git but with no luck (`git log` or `git reset` works btw.). Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After manually deleting the `index.lock` file from `.git` directory has solved the issue and now everything's working fine.