# Blogdown, Git and RStudio: Unable to Stage public/ folder

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio, blogdown

I am very new to blogdown and git. While staging the files/folders (using RStudio) inside the project folder, I am unable to choose the following folders:

[image: RStudio-Git-Blogdown]

Can anybody let me know why this is happening and how can I stage/commit/push the above folders to the remote repository?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Click the checkbox?

Comment: @Yihui Yes, I selected all the folders and tried clicking on the checkbox but in vain. I also tried right clicking on the folders and select stage but with the same result. This is happening with only the 4 folders viz. "public/", "static", "themes" and "visualization-website.Rproj" and that too when I use the Git interface within RStudio. I am able to commit and push the aforementioned folders using the standalone Github windows tool but not through RStudio.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea then. You may open a question on https://community.rstudio.com and point to your post here.

Comment: @avinax I am facing a similar problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: the question is also open an community.rstudio.com: https://community.rstudio.com/t/blogdown-unable-to-stage-and-commit/6621. Something with the IDE being non responsive enough with folder containing lots of file could be the issue. You could use the terminal to add the folder : `git add public`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, so for future reference here are two ways I found to deal with it:

1. Try staging the files using the **RStudio terminal**. Open the terminal (Tool > Terminal > New Terminal) and type in `git add -A`. Then close the terminal. For me, this instantly staged all the files and let me commit and push them from within R Studio.
2. Download the **GitHub desktop client**. Within the client, add your R project file as a repository. You can then use the 'fetch origin', 'commit master' and 'push origin' buttons to commit and push your folders. So you'd use RStudio as you normally would to edit your website, but use the GitHub client to commit and push.

Hope this helps. These solutions were provided by users at RStudio community
https://community.rstudio.com/t/blogdown-unable-to-stage-and-commit/6621/4

Comment: if `git add -A` in the terminal doesn't work, [this question][1] might be helpful. 


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004148/another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository