# cannot add files to git commit

Tags: git, bash

I have tried several solutions in this forum, but I cannot add files to be committed. I use `git add -A` but my git bash just freezes. I have removed the *index.lock* file. It seems to be created every time I run `git add -A` , but nothing happens. It just sits there with a blinking cursor. I upgraded my git bash, re-initialized my project, but it is still the same issue. I have tried many solutions from the below thread and similar ones:

[Another git process seems to be running in this repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004148/another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository/38004454)

Full error:

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
>   an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
>   are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
>   may have crashed in this repository earlier:
>   remove the file manually to continue.

I am using Windows 10 and use atom if that helps.

Comment: How many files are you committing? And how long are you waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to check if there is indeed another git process still running.

Second, check what [your untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801554/6309) (that you are trying to add to the index) are:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

You might have way too many: adjust your `.gitignore` accordingly.

Once that is done, try again, from a CMD session (close Atom)

---

As mentioned by [the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2247061/user2247061) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862386/cannot-add-files-to-git-commit/47862752#comment82727308_47862752), the issue comes from a folder named "`Aux`".
And, as explained in "[Why can't we make `CON`, `PRN`, `Null` folder in Windows?](https://superuser.com/a/613335/141)", you cannot create or delete a folder named "`Aux"`.

Ideally, you would delete it first:

```
DEL \\.\c:\path\to\Aux
```

Then you can try your `git add -A` again.

Comment: this helped a bit. i'm trying to upload a React Js project, so i'm not sure if you're familiar, but i was able to upload everything except the folder containing my project files itself. i have gotten rid of my node_modules folder which significantly reduced file size and count,  but something is still freezing. my project folder isn't particularly big and has few files in it (compared to the other folders i was able to upload), although i'm not sure what constitues that? is there a way to further narrow it down to a file or folder or some sort without having to go 1 by 1?

Comment: well i found the problem folder. its a folder that i cannot edit due to some permissions error and i'm unable to change it in windows. i tried deleting the folder but it says the folder is too large, but there is only one javascript file in there that is 1kb. i renamed it, made a copy of it, but the permissions error is blocking me still. the folder is named "Aux" and it seems as if i use this name the permissions on it change immediately. although i have not tried changing permissions (or changed it initially) when i created this folder through git bash.

Comment: @user2247061 Can you delete it from a CMD session (instead of bash)?

Comment: @user2247061 I have edited my answer to explain why a folder named "Aux" is problematic. (and how to solve the issue).

Comment: thank you so much. i was able to delete the folder and remake with a new name and all is fine now.