# Im getting an error on git bash unable to create file exists

Tags: git, git-commit

Here is the problem [image]
What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another git process seems to be running in this repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004148/another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rm -f ./.git/index.lock` and try to `git checkout` again

Comment: If you think it's helpful ,i would be nice if you could accpet this as accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

As the log says, there might be another running process which needs the lock. `ps aux` should give some clues. If no other processes are running, the lock may be the leftover of a process that has been killed or ended by accident before it finishes the job. You could manually remove the lock file and then try `git checkout` again.

Comment: Where would I find the ps aux? How would I remove the lock?

Comment: @ImaniM.Jackson `ps aux` is a command that you can run in git bash or bash shell. You can remove it by deleting the file or run the command `rm -f <lock filepath>`.

Comment: would you manually delete the file from the folder its in and remake it or is it in the .git hidden folder?

Comment: @ImaniM.Jackson it's the file index.lock under .git. You can see its full path in the log.