# git Commit failed

Tags: git, git-commit

I am getting following error during `git` `commit`

> Commit failed with error          0 files committed, 3 files failed to
>   commit:           Unable to create
>   'C:/xampp/htdocs/project/.git/index.lock': File exists
>
> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
>       an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
>       are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
>       may have crashed in this repository earlier:
>       remove the file manually to continue.

I closed all open terminal and tried again and again, but could not get success.

Thanks for suggesion.

Comment: Try restarting your PC.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38004148/6352677

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another git process seems to be running in this repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004148/another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be two git operations running at the same time.

Try to delete the index.lock file to unlock further operations:

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

or if there are more locked files:

```
 rm -f .git/*.lock
```