# How can I remove my ssh key if I ve lost it?

Tags: git, ssh, reset

How can I remove my `/~.ssh` if I've lost it? I have to join a new project but if I am trying to commit, add or push anything I get an error:

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an
>   editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are
>   terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process may have
>   crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to
>   continue.

Is there any git comand to reset all my user settings and start using git like on a new computer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like the problem is not with `~/.ssh`, but possibly with a `git` command not finishing properly. Does the `.git` directory in the project have an `index.lock` file in it?

Answer (score 0):

This is generally seen with local commands (`git add`), which do not involve any network communication, and won't use SSH or HTTPS at all.
See [here for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38004148/6309).

If `rm -f .git/index.lock` is not enough, try at least to reboot, and to repeat your command right after reboot, to ensure no other process is preempting any local Git resource.