# References missing after Git rebase in Git extension

Tags: github, reference, visual-studio-2019, git-extensions

I'm trying to troubleshoot a colleague. Basically, we are working on the same project. He used Git extension to add a repository to his computer. Then he checked the branch we are going to work on. I was the one that created that branch. It start fine on my end, but he gets 140+ errors. After a quick check with him, it seem to be that the references don't work. Now I'll explain all the step we went through since the beginning.

It started this morning. Neither of us could start the project (despite it being a copy of one that was already on the repository). I looked into it and apparently one of the reference wasn't working. I simply right clicked on the website and added a reference. It worked on my end and I could start it. I thus pushed that change to the branch.

Then I contacted my colleagues and went with him through the process. When he loaded his git extension he had some 130+ differences despite not having done anything on the project yet (he was waiting for me to solve it). He tried multiple times to reset it. Eventually, we figured the problem and followed what [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004148/another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository) on another post. It worked and he was able to reset the changes. From there, he went back to git extension, and fetched the changes. Then, on the most recent version of the remote branch, right clicked and rebased his local branch. No error or issue still.
Then, when he re-opened visual studio 2019 and tried to build the project, he got about 149 errors. All these errors were from the fact that it couldn't find some of the reference at the beginning of the cs files. many of the "using" werent working. I tried rebuilding the solution, but to no avail.

I do not know what to do. He has the same files as me but it isn't working. OS is the same (windwos 10) IDE is the same (visual studio 2019) and we both used Git extension. Anyone knows what can cause this kind of mass loss of reference?

I'm by no mean an expert with Git, but I don't think I did anything capable of this. I have pushed my version, and he rebased his branch on it (He hadn't changed anything yet)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to first establish whether it is Git Extensions issue, git issue or user issue.

You posts seems to allude it is the app that is doing something wrong. I doubt it - because we would have been inundated with bug reports. I also doubt it is git to blame for the same reason. So it is likely the 3rd reason.

First of all, for sanity checks try cloning the same repo on your computer to a different location and try building it. It is possible that in your original repo you have untracked files that are ignored - and that makes it build. But because they have not been checked in - they are absent when cloned, and hence break other builds.

Also try running commands from cli - GE is just a UI that runs all the same git commands, no magic there. You can see git command log by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or via menu *Tools > Git command log*.