# What can I do, when pushing to GitHub brings error

Tags: github, directory, repository

I have been trying to push my code to GitHub but it's saying "Another git process seems to be running in this repository" I don't understand, pls what could be the problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you use a C library to push or do you use command line tools?

Answer (score 0):

If the full error message is (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38004148/6309))

```
Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue
```

Start with `rm -f .git/index.lock` (assuming indeed no other git process is running).

Then you can try again.