# How do I get Intellij to commit to github?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have made a Intellij project and tried to commit it to Github and got this error:

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process may have crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to continue.

I have no idea what to do. There aren't any other git processes, and I don't know what "git commit" is.

I tried some things and nothing changed.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Have you entered a commit message somewhere? Do you see a window, tab, or another editor that shows a commit message? If so, save and close it. You should be good to go. Check out this page, maybe it helps: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html

Comment: Does the issue persist if you logout/login or reboot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Another git process seems to be running in this repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004148/another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository)

Comment: @CrazyCoder yep.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen where do I use that command?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to configure git for Intellij first.

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html

> Configure commit options: **Settings/Preferences** | **Version Control** | **Commit**

Then, you can commit locally:

> 1. Open the vertical Commit tool window **Alt+0** located on the left.
> 2. As your changes are ready to be committed, select the corresponding files or an entire changelist.
> 3. etc, see article ...

There are some helpful command when you are set up:

> Commit tool window **Alt+0**
> Commit **Ctrl+K**
> Commit and Push **Ctrl+Alt+K**
> Push **Ctrl+Shift+K**

Comment: I already have the commit settings the way I want, the problem is it won't let me commit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, I just had to delete the 'HEAD' file in the '.git' folder.
Thanks for the help!